# Flash Memory device now shows 31MB capacity after using as linux live-usb device

Tags: windows-7, usb-flash-drive, format

The actual capacity of the USB device is 8GB, but after using it as a live-usb device the available memory has reduced to 31MB. I tried formatting the device but that does not solve the problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The chances are that the drive has been partitioned.  Right Click computer > Manage.

Go to Storage > Disk Management.

Locate your USB Drive and delete all the partitions and volumes on it.  You should then be able to create a new single partition which uses all the space on the drive.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the partitions on the Flash device. Blow away all the partitions and repartition it.